# Android: I just want to have a validation for avoiding duplication of email address

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

My error:

at com.me.samplesqlite.DatabaseHelper.checkEmailExists(DatabaseHelper.java:83) at com.me.samplesqlite.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:67) at com.me.samplesqlite.SignUp.onSignUpClick(SignUp.java:84)

I am getting an error (force stop) after i filled-up all the fields in my registration module.

I just want to have a validation for avoiding duplication of email address. Someone please help me with this kind of validation? This is a simple registration with some validations. So, my target here is to avoid duplication of inserted data for email address.

My goal is when there is an existing email address it will not be able to register again with the same email add

```
**package com.me.samplesqlite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class SignUp extends Activity
{
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);
    }

    public void onSignUpClick(View view)
    {

        if(view.getId() == R.id.btnSignUp)
        {

            EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
            EditText email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
            EditText pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
            EditText cpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtConfirmPass);

            String sname = name.getText().toString();
            String suname = uname.getText().toString();
            String semail = email.getText().toString();
            String spass = pass.getText().toString();
            String scpass = cpass.getText().toString();

            if(sname.length()==0 && suname.length()==0 && semail.length()==0 && spass.length()==0)
            {
                name.requestFocus();
                name.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                uname.requestFocus();
                uname.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                email.requestFocus();
                email.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                pass.requestFocus();
                pass.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
            }
            else if(!sname.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
            {
                name.requestFocus();
                name.setError("ENTER ONLY ALPHABETICAL CHARACTER");
            }
            else if(!(spass.length()>5))
            {
                pass.requestFocus();
                pass.setError("PASSWORD MUST HAVE MORE THAN 5 CHARACTERS");
            }

            else if (!scpass.equals(spass))
            {
                cpass.requestFocus();
                cpass.setError("PASSWORD DON'T MATCH");
            }
            else if(!semail.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+"))
            {
                email.requestFocus();
                email.setError("INVALID EMAIL ADDRESS");
            }
            else
            {
                Contact b = new Contact();
                boolean isEmailExist = helper.insertContact(b);
                if(isEmailExist)
                {
                    // notify user
                    Toast mail = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Email Already Exist." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
                    mail.show();

                }
                else
                {
                    // proceed
                    Contact c = new Contact();
                    c.setName(sname);
                    c.setUName(suname);
                    c.setEmail(semail);
                    c.setPass(spass);

                    helper.insertContact(c);

                    //popup message
                    Toast password = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Data has been saved." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
                    password.show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
                //insert the details on database

            }


        }
        if(view.getId() == R.id.btnCancelSign)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
**



package com.me.samplesqlite;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;



public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
        private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
        private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
        private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";

        SQLiteDatabase db;

        private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts (id integer primary key not null , " +
                "name text not null , uname text not null , email text not null , pass text not null);";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
            this.db = db;
        }

        public boolean insertContact(Contact c)
        {
            boolean isEmailExist = false;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            String query = "select * from contacts";
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            int count = cursor.getCount();


            values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME , c.getName());
            values.put(COLUMN_UNAME , c.getUName());
            values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL , c.getEmail());
            values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

            if(checkEmailExists(c.getEmail()))
            {
                isEmailExist = true;
            }
            else
            {
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            }
            db.close();
            return isEmailExist;
        }

        private boolean checkEmailExists(String email) {
            String query = new StringBuilder().append("Select ")
                    .append(email).append(" from ").append(TABLE_NAME)
                    .toString();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,
                    new String[] { email });
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            } else {
                cursor.close();
                return false;
            }
        }


        public String searchPass(String uname)
        {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "select uname, pass from "+ TABLE_NAME;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null);

            String a,b;
            b = "not found";
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {
                    a = cursor.getString(0);
                    b = cursor.getString(1);

                    if(a.equals(uname))
                    {
                        b = cursor.getString(1);
                        break;
                    }

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return b;
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
            db.execSQL(query);
            this.onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is your question you getting error which force closing your app or you not able to validate duplicate email?

Comment: I filled-up all the fields in my registration module when I press the register button it force close.

Comment: ok then please post your log..

Comment: one thing you initializing  your database object in wrong place put it into oncreate method
DatabaseHelper helper;

in oncreate method put
helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

Comment: okay.. in my Sign-up.java is there any wrong there?

Comment: in the below part of my code you will see my DatabaseHelper.java code..

Comment: yeh initialize your DatabaseHelper object in oncreate method because it holds the activity context when activity is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

relpace your checkEmailExists with below

```
private boolean checkEmailExists(String email) {
        String query = "Select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where email like '"+email+"'";


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,
                null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

2.Replace your create table query with this and let me know

```
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table IF NOT EXISTS contacts (id integer primary key not null , " +
            "name text not null , uname text not null , email text not null , pass text not null);";
```

3.Also you passing blank object to database for email check replace that with below

```
 Contact b = new Contact();
                    b.setName(sname);
                    b.setUName(suname);
                    b.setEmail(semail);
                    b.setPass(spass);

                boolean isEmailExist = helper.insertContact(b);
```

Comment: It still not working after I register it force close.

Comment: now its time to check your DatabaseHelper code plz update your error stack so we can assist you better

Comment: at com.me.samplesqlite.DatabaseHelper.checkEmailExists(DatabaseHelper.java:83)
            at com.me.samplesqlite.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:67)
            at com.me.samplesqlite.SignUp.onSignUpClick(SignUp.java:84)

Comment: @igydiamzon at the time of checking you also inserting new contact  in db then no need to call it in else statement once more after email check

Comment: @igydiamzon if it helped you then you can upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

i think you are comparing it wrong. In your this part of code

```
 private boolean checkEmailExists(String email) {
            String query = new StringBuilder().append("Select ")
                    .append(email).append(" from ").append(TABLE_NAME)
                    .toString();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,
                    new String[] { email });
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            } else {
                cursor.close();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

in this function you are taking the email which is enters by the user and putting it in the database directly but where you have done the matching ? 
which part of code shows that you are comparing the email from the database email addresses .

what you should have done is 
1. Make a function in the database which returns you a list on emails form the data base , lets suppose that you have 5 records , each has email filed, so make a function which returns the list of only emails , let say this function is called emailList();

2. call this function in your activity code and get the list , as I said above suppose you have 5 record so you have first to check the length of list , let say its length if of index 4

3 on button click event before saving data , you are most like to run the for loop , get each email from list from index zero and compare it with the current entered email address by the user , if it exist stop there and tell the user about the error if not then continue to save data to the database and sign up would be proceed

that all you need to implement.